# Nested Composite Keys

Tags: hibernate, jpa, composite-key

I have the following Composite Keys for two entities

```
@Embeddable
public class ProductId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "Id", columnDefinition = "bigint identity(1,1)")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ProductTypeName")
    private String name;
....
}

@Embeddable
public class ApplicationId implements Serializable{
    @Column(name = "Id", columnDefinition = "bigint identity(1,1)",
            nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name="id",
                       column=@Column(name="ProductId",
                                  columnDefinition = "bigint identity(1,1)",
                                  nullable = false, insertable = false,
                                  updatable = false))
    private ProductId productId;
....
}
```

I have two different entities both with the above defined Composite Keys. My problem is with nesting composite keys, which I am trying to put it to work but it is failing when hibernate scan the entity which has the ApplicationId embbedable object as its PK (here is the mapping for the one giving problems)

```
@Entity(name = "Application")
@Table(name = "Application")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Application {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ApplicationId applicationPk;

    @MapsId("productId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "ProductId", referencedColumnName = "Id",
                           nullable = false, insertable = true,
                           updatable = true),
                  @JoinColumn(name = "ProductTypeName",
                           referencedColumnName = "ProductTypeName",
                           nullable = false, insertable = true,
                           updatable = true)})
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_Application_Product")
    private Product product;
....}
```

Hibernate complains with the following error `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: ProductId in Application`

Comment: For anyone having this issue is better to use the IdClass approach. Also in my opinion is a better approach since all entities participating in the composite id are annotated with the @Id annotation and the code is IMHO more readable and easier to understand. If anyone needs an example for this just let me know I will post the answer.